# Exporting byte[] results to corrupted .zip

Tags: c#, .net, clr, filestream

I am trying to make a CLR with .NET 2.0 integrated into MS SQL Server 2008. I call an API with and I should receive a .zip as response. I store the response into a Stream and I want to export this file to a physical .zip file.
I tried exporting the file with C# and SQL (BCB OR OLE) and all resulted into a corrupted file. So, I believe I am doing something wrong with in the making of the stream.

The C# code is the following:

```
private static byte[] GetStreamFileResult(Cookie loginCookie, Guid fileGuid, String baseUri)
    {
        byte[] output = null;
        //String result = null;
        string url = "some url"

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        cookies.Add(new Uri(url), loginCookie);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookies;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        HttpWebResponse resp = response as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            CopyStream(dataStream, ms);
            output = ms.ToArray();
        }

        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return output;
    }
```

The C# code to export the zip is the following:

```
 File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\folder\\t.zip", stream); // Requires System.IO
```

The copy from stream to stream:

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output))
            {
                writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }                
    }
```

Comment: Could you show what the CopyStream method does?

Comment: or even simpler. why not call download file method?

Comment: @RMH especially since there's an inbuilt `dataStream.CopyTo(ms);` method - so: if the problem is `CopyStream`, it should be really easy to fix

Comment: @MarcGravell agreed, but it could be that the method does something extra besides simply copying the stream. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @RMH I updated the question with the code you asked

Comment: @MarcGravell in .Net 2.0 I could not find any build in function.. So I made one.

Comment: @Steve Because I am really new to C#, how could I call the download file method since I have just have a byte[] ?

Comment: `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are classes intended to be used when you're working with `Stream`s containing *text*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The API documentation states that this call will return me a zip file containing 3 XML files. The zip file will be in form of a byte[]. So how could get this if not with the mentioned classes?

Comment: @Manos via `Read` in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CopyStream` is broken. You need to talk binary. You're currently treating binary zip data as though it were text:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you, now I understand my error.

Comment: @Manos note: if `dataStream.Length` works (it isn't required to), you can optimize a lot of this by allocating the right-sized array initially. You still need to loop to fill it, but changing offset and count each iteration.

Comment: @Manos hopefully this also demonstrates the importance of including all relevant code in the original question :)

Comment: You are right. I did not include in the original question because I thought this part was working properly, since the input and the output was the same. But in the future I will include everything in any case ;)